# How to assign back data frame columns using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I need to modify some columns in data frame using `dplyr`. For example,

```
select(mtcars,hp:am)+99
```

How can I assign back to the data frame `mtcars`?

```
mtcars[,4:9]=select(mtcars,hp:am)+99
```

would work, but it uses absolute index 4:9, and I want to avoid that (which is why I am using `dplyr` `:` operation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cold borrow some of the logic from the `subset()` command to get a list of variable indices

```
varindex <- function(x, select) {
    if (missing(select)) 
        TRUE
    else {
        nl <- as.list(seq_along(x))
        names(nl) <- names(x)
        eval(substitute(select), nl, parent.frame())
    }
}
```

And then use that for updating your data.frame

```
cols <- varindex(mtcars, hp:am)
mtcars[,cols] <- mtcars[,cols]+99
```

If you want to stick with `dplyr`, the correct function to use is `mutate()`, not `select()`. Use

```
mutate_at(mtcars, vars(hp:am), function(x) x+99)
```

Comment: a little bit complicated that what i thought. is it possible to have any simpler solution?

Comment: @hxd1011 I added a dplyr solution as well.

Comment: Thank your for complete solution with different options, and you taught me  how to discover by myself instead of directly give me the solution !